# Get mouse X position from clicked in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mouseevent

In React I'm trying to get mouse X position after click, if I click in middle of page and move it right **it must start counting from 0** not from actual `e.clientX` would count

here is What I do but seems like doesn't work

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [startPosition, setStartPosition] = useState(0)

  const mouseMove = (e) => {
    console.log(e.clientX - startPosition)
  }

  const mouseClick = (e) => {
    setStartPosition(e.clientX)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseClick)
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousedown", mouseClick)
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove)
    }
  },[])

  return (
    <div className='App' />
  );
}

export default App
```

this code still prints `e.clientX` not actual cordinates from clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `useEffect` while using window events `[]` as second argument isn't necessary

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseClick)
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousedown", mouseClick)
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove)
    }
  })
```

after doing this it works now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get position when click, you need using `onClick` Event Listeners.

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [startPosition, setStartPosition] = useState(0);

  const mouseClick = (e) => {
    setStartPosition(e.clientX);
    console.log(e.clientX);
  };

  return <div className="App" onClick={mouseClick} />;
};
```

> Maybe you need add height style for `.App` like: `.App: { height: 100vh }`

Comment: I need to get mouseX after mouse is down not after down and up, also my code updates state when I mousedown but doesnt substract after `mousemove`, also that action must happen on **window** on on specific component